Переадресация запросов в локальной сети
У нас есть два компа, подключенных через radmin. Компьютер 1 имеет оборудование, которое подключается к программе по ip. К примеру 192.168.18.203. Нужно сделать так, чтобы компьютер 2 в такой же программе смог подключиться к оборудованию (образно по тому же айпишнику), чтобы компьютер 1 выступал в роли маршрутизатора.
В качестве интернета выступает модем.
Пробовал через роуты что-то сделать, но особо ничего не вышло...

Подробную схему, с настройками каждого сетевого интерфейса и маршрутами каждого узла - в студию.,
